# Spring actuator health check - how to ensure that there is an active connection to database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I want to return status `ok` with 200 code only if my application is up and running and there is an active connection to the database. 
the wanted behaviour of the health check is :

- If the app is running but the db is down - **DOWN**
- if the app is down and the database is up - **DOWN**
- If the app is up and there is an active connection to database - **UP**

So I created a custom health check class but I dont know how to check if the database connection is active and valid in the spring way

```
@Component
public class HealthCheck implements HealthIndicator {

  @Override
  public Health health() {
      int errorCode = check();
      if (errorCode != 0) {
          return Health.down()
          .withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
    }
    return Health.up().build();
 }

 public int check() {
    // Check if there is an active connection to the database
    return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the built-in [`DataSourceHealthIndicator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/jdbc/DataSourceHealthIndicator.html) that will be auto-configured when your application has a `DataSource`? It will execute a query that's appropriate to the database you are using to check that it's available.

Comment: I didnt know that there is a built-in indicator that check if the data source is available, after I read about DataSourceHealthIndicator there is no point to implement my own datasource check, thanks !!

Comment: `management.health.db.enabled=true `